# Installing .exe using wine but program is nowhere to be found

Tags: wine

I'm a new Ubuntu user and just installed Wine yesterday to help with my .exe programs.

Some programs seem to work but some others, while the installer shows up and you do click next / click install, after the GUI shows its installation process up to completion... After completion the program is nowhere to be found!!!

I'm sure its something simple but i can't figure out why there is an inconsistency between programs

Comment: Try Restarting...

Comment: What Is The Program You Are Trying To Install?

Answer (score 2):

You may be overestimating the usefulness of Wine.

Wine is a compatibility layer. It does not work like Windows and is not a replacement for Windows.

Not all Windows applications will run on Wine, and for the ones that do, they often require various degrees of application-specific manual configuration.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using system-wide Wine - then you may want to find the installed executable  by using special Wine file-manager:

```
winefile
```

Navigate to `C:\`, `Program Files`, `programname` (an example) and execute `program.exe` (an example).

---

Also please note:

1. not all applications work good on Wine, consult with http://appdb.winehq.org/ for the support status.
2. some applications need additional configuration of Wine, which is done best by using [PlayOnLinux](https://www.playonlinux.com) (installable as simple as `sudo apt-get install playonlinux`). It creates shortcuts by itself or by asking user to do so.